# How to create a matrix(without numpy library)

Tags: python

I created this one,

```
n,m = 3, 3

Matrix = [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(m)]

print (Matrix)
```

But I want the matrix to be more visual like a current one, every "list" behind each other

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I'd like to use iterations like "for" to create it because it will be more easy to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `function` to display it:

```
def display(m):
    for r in m:
        print(r)
```

So printing `Matrix` would normally result in:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

but, if instead you do `display(Matrix)` after defining this `function` somewhere in your code, you will get:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

where each `row` in the `matrix` is beneath each other.

---

And of course, if you didn't want to define a `matrix` populated with `0s`, you can just hard code the contents:

```
Matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

which to show the `function` works, outputs the following  from `display(Matrix)`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

---

*Note that it is probably better to call this a **`2-dimensional` `list`** rather than a `Matrix` to avoid confusion.*

Comment: I think the first answer works, I want a matrix to fill it with numbers, according to Levehnstein algorithm of two strings, in function of its similarities between characters. I think it will work isn't it?

Comment: @ZRTSTR Your question seems to be more about displaying the `lists`, rather than creating them... If you have written a specific `function` that will give the `Levenhnstein` output, I can try to incorporate it into this, but that wasn't really what you asked. As it stands, this answers your question, and you should really ask a new question about that algorithm for people to come help you on... Hope this works for you though, please `accept` if it does.

Comment: Your answer was helped me, don't worry about it, I will create another discussion.

Comment: @ZRTSTR Yes, that is the right thing to do! Please `accept` (click the green tick) thank you.